# Can I temporarily modify an existing remote website with ScratchPad/Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, firefox, variables, scripting, greasemonkey

A website I do not own has the following code added to it with a `<script>` tag. Would it be possible for me to change the `url` variable inside the `a.ajax`, using the Firefox's ScratchPad, or Greasemonkey?

If so, how?
If not, why? And is it at least possible to modify the `c` variable, and if so, how?

```
validateUsername: function ()
{
    clearTimeout(b.signUp.usernameValidationTimer);
    b.signUp.usernameValidationTimer = null;
    var c = a("#register-username").val();
    if(3 > c.length)
        b.signUp.hideValidationError("#register-username"), a("#register-username").removeClass("validate_ok");
    else
    {
        if(b.signUp.usernameValidation == c) return !1;
        b.signUp.hideValidationError("#register-username");
        b.signUp.usernameValidation = c;
        a("#register-username").addClass("ajax-load");
        a.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/" + b.signUp.getMarket() + "/xhr/json/validate-email.php",
            xhrFields:{ withCredentials: !0 },
            data:{ username: c },
            success: function (c)
            {
                a("#register-username").removeClass("ajax-load");
                "object" == typeof c ? "1" == c.status ? b.signUp.hideValidationError("#register-username", !0)  :b.signUp.showValidationError("#register-username", c.message) :
                b.signUp.showValidationError("#register-username")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to do this one time, just testing, or do you want to do it automatically every time the page is loaded?  Both are possible-ish but the focus of the answer is different.  Also, **how** (or into what) do you want to modify the variable? ... PS: the "deobfuscation" tag does not seem to apply.

Comment: I'd like to do it just once granted that it works. I'd like to change the URL variable into a .php file of my own (if that's possible?) if that's not possible, then I'll look into it later. The new values aren't the point of this question, it's about how to do it.

Comment: You give the new values, as specific as possible, so that we can be clear on what you are really trying to do.  The question and the comment are still a bit ambiguous. See [ask] and the pages linked from there. ... You've given the "before", now we need the desired "after" to clear up the ambiguity.  This helps *you* get more, better, and faster answers, and more upvotes.

Comment: Okay... well.. currently, the url variable is  ""/" + b.signUp.getMarket() + "/xhr/json/validate-email.php"". If possible, I'd like to set it to "http://www.mydomain.com/test-validation.php" instead.

Comment: @И-, you'd have to redefine the entire function, a la `window.validateUsername = function () { ... , url: 'mydomain.com/test-validation.php', ... }`. If that's what you're looking for, I can turn it into an answer for you to approve.

Comment: Well, that's close enough, I think. You can turn it in as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the `c` variable in the code in question relatively simple using Firefox (no addon required either).

I've created a simple test page which shows the date/time when loaded:

```js
var now = new Date();
var year = now.getFullYear();
var month = now.getMonth() + 1;
var day = now.getDate();
var hour = now.getHours();
var minutes = now.getMinutes();
var seconds = now.getSeconds();
var ampm = (hour < 12 ? "am" : "pm");

if (hour == 0) {
    hour = 24;
}

document.write(
    year.toString() + '-' +
    (month < 10 ? '0' + month.toString() : month.toString()) + '-' +
    (day < 10 ? '0' + day.toString() : day.toString()) + ' ' +
    (hour < 10 ? '0' + hour.toString() : hour > 12 ? (hour - 12).toString() : hour.toString()) + ':' +
    (minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes.toString() : minutes.toString()) + ':' +
    (seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds.toString() : seconds.toString()) + ' ' +
    ampm
);
```

**Result:**

[image: Printed date/time result]

---

## Guide to Firefox debugging

1. **Enable the Firefox Debugger:**

   [image: Enable the Firefox Debugger]
2. **Find the script in question, and set a breakpoint in the code (important! →) *after* the variable has been assigned:**

   *note - you can set more than one breakpoint.*

   [image: Find script, set breakpoint]
3. **Cause the script to execute:**

   Whether it's by refreshing the page or clicking a button.
4. **Firefox will pause execution on the line(s) from step 2:**

   [image: Breakpoint reached]
5. **Look for the desired variable(s) on the right side; click on its value, and modify it. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> when finished:**

   [image: Modify value]

   **Modified variable/value will flash yellow:**

   [image: Yellow flash after modify]
6. **Resume script execution:**

   [image: Resume script execution]
7. **And the results!:**

   *notice the date difference (from **24** to **20**)*

   [image: Modified results]